# Toolbar ImageView not clickabele

Tags: android, imageview, fragment, onclicklistener, toolbar

[image]

This is the image of a fragment containing a fragmelayout where I will add fragments on button clicks of Blog,Hints and Forums. I have included a toolbar xml at top with two imageviews. Problem is I am getting button clicks but not included toolbar imageview clicks. Any solutions?

Toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    >

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/header_gray"
      android:focusable="true"
      >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHomeToolbarBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
        android:focusable="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHomeToolbarBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imgHomeToolbarBack"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:text="@string/edit"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_medium_semi"
        fontPath="@string/font_regular"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHomeToolbarLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHomeToolbarCalendar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_margin_5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/calender"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the common toolbar code.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
    >
  <include
      layout="@layout/toolbar_home"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      />
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/llCommunitySections"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBlog"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/nabta_blog"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        fontPath="@string/font_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/textDarkBlue"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHints"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/hints_tips"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        fontPath="@string/font_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/blogGreyText"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnForums"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/forums"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        fontPath="@string/font_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/blogGreyText"
        />
  </LinearLayout>
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/flCategories"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

After setting onClickListener in onActivityCreated insted of butterknife injection I am getting clicks on search icon but not on back icon. I have toggled visibility of back icon in some fragments. This is a fragment with other fragments loading in flCategories.

OnClickListener's code:

```
imgHomeToolbarBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
  @Override public void onClick(View v)
  {
    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  }
});
imgHomeToolbarCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
  @Override public void onClick(View v)
  {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Search Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Toast is occuring but not other one.

Comment: post some code so we can look into it

Comment: @AkshayKatariya please have a look

Comment: also java code for your click listener..

Comment: @AkshayKatariya please check

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Actually I was not adding the new fragments to backstack and hence backstack was empty so it was not going back.